# EntityFramework DbContext constructor takes more than 5 secs - Performance Issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

**Class definition of AuthContext which has almost 30-35 DbSets**

```
    public class AuthContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        internal static string connectionstring
        {
            get
            {
                return connection_string;
            }
        }
        public AuthContext() : base(connectionstring)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Class1> Class1 { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Class2> Class2 { get; set; }
    }
```

**Usage of the AuthContext**

```
public class AuthRepository : IDisposable
{
    private AuthContext _ctx;
    public AuthRepository()
    {
        _ctx = new AuthContext();
    }

    public void somemethod(Class1 item)
    {
        _ctx.Class1.add(item);
        _ctx.SaveChanges()
    }
}
```

Authcontext constructor takes around 5-6 seconds to load, how can we initialize singleton object & use that for all the WebAPI requests?

I have read documentation and found that EF make sure that it creates singleton object for each dataset.

please suggest changes in order to improve the performance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you to profile generated SQL queries, instead of creating singleton context.

Comment: Where are you setting the connection string? Maybe the constructor is getting an empty string which causes the performance issue??

Comment: connection string is a global static property. get
            {
                return connection_string; (reading from config at common place)
            }

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov does EF generates any SQL while constructor call?

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado I'm always getting correct connection string.

Comment: @MiteshPrajapati, it is good time to figure out it.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov would you like to suggest some tools for profiling sql?

Comment: @MiteshPrajapati, firstly you can try to log queries: paste this code into constructor `Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);`. Tools depend on particular server, you can find them by yourself

Comment: we are using azure webapp. so I found some tools like Visual Studio performance tools, azure application insights as well as JetBrains.

Comment: If you don't need 35 DbSets/entities to accomplish authentication, then split off your DbContext so that it only has entities and relationships you need for time-sensitive operations. Is this running against AzureSQL? In my experience that Data platform was ill-suited for high-volume time-sensitive operations. It may be better now, but I'm still a skeptic. :) If it's an SQL Server on VM or such a simple profiler is ExpressProfiler.

Comment: I suggest you step through the code, no way that it should take that long. I suspect that its something else and not the constructor. please step through the code to confirm its the constructor i find this hard to believe unless the connection string is invalid, but then that would be a different story

Comment: @StevePy yes, it's running against AzureSQL.